# Scrap data from "dinamic" XHR - this request does not appears in HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, request, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to scrape data from URL that get the data from an API. But, the problem of the XHR request it's that the URL generate is dinamic.

I mean, whenever we do a request in the same URL, the XHR API URL changes.

The same resource after reload request.

[image]
[image]

It's the first time that I see something like it. I don't understand the logic that was generating this URL to do the request in the API.

I'm trying to use "playwright" to intercept this XHR, but I don't know if this lib can do it.

In this case, if I can get the XHR requests that this page does, I'll achieve to do the same requests that the pages is doing.

Is this thought a good way to go or would it be better to try something else?

Some tips to investigate better the HTML to try generate this URL?

I can pass the URL if you need.

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: @AndrejKesely https://precodahora.tcepb.tc.br/categorias/cafe-torrado-extratos-essencias-e-concentrados-de-cafe

Comment: The hexa number in the URL is created dynamically  (specifically in the file https://precodahora.tcepb.tc.br/_next/static/chunks/2674-467da91c8b7b81dd.js - you need to use Js debugger in the Web Developer Tools to see this and reverse engineer the logic). But I see the site is using cloudflare protection, so you need circumvent this too.

Comment: yep @AndrejKesely, I've tried some thing to by pass it the cloudflare. Do you recommend anything?